# Update multiple columns using union all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to update multiple columns from one table using union all from two other table.

Here is an example:

```
UPDATE CustomerTrans 
SET SumQuantity = (SELECT SUM(x.Quantity)
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT * 
                        FROM InventoryTrans  
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM InventoryTranstemp) x 
                   JOIN
                       CustomerTrans a ON a.TrnDocumentID = x.TrnDocumentID),
    SumPrice = (SELECT SUM(x.Price)   
                FROM 
                    (SELECT * 
                     FROM InventoryTrans  
                     UNION ALL 
                     SELECT * 
                     FROM InventoryTranstemp) x 
                JOIN
                    CustomerTrans a ON a.TrnDocumentID = x.TrnDocumentID)
```

As you can see two selects are exactly the same. How can I avoid it?

Accepted answers also using join instead of union

```
UPDATE CustomerTrans 
SET SumQuantity = (SELECT SUM(x.Quantity),
    SumPrice = (SELECT SUM(x.Price))
                FROM 
                    (SELECT * 
                     FROM InventoryTrans  
                     UNION ALL 
                     SELECT * 
                     FROM InventoryTranstemp) x 
                JOIN
                    CustomerTrans a ON a.TrnDocumentID = x.TrnDocumentID)
```

Using this statement, I'm getting an error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   with x as

   (
   select * from InventoryTrans 
   UNION ALL
    Select * from InventoryTranstemp
   )
   update CustomerTrans set 
  SumQuantity= (select sum (x.Quantity) from x 

   where CustomerTrans.TrnDocumentID=x.TrnDocumentID),

   sumPrice= (select sum (x.sumPrice) from x

   where CustomerTrans.TrnDocumentID=x.TrnDocumentID)
```

Comment: It would be great if you use Aliases

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 with tmp as
(

   select f1.TrnDocumentID, f1.Quantity, f1.Price from InventoryTrans f1 inner join CustomerTrans f2 on f1.TrnDocumentID=f2.TrnDocumentID 
   UNION ALL
   Select f1.TrnDocumentID, f1.Quantity, f1.Price from InventoryTranstemp f1 inner join CustomerTrans f2 on f1.TrnDocumentID=f2.TrnDocumentID 
)
update f0
set f0.SumQuantity=sum (f1.Quantity), f0.SumPrice =sum (f1.Price)
from CustomerTrans f0 inner join tmp f1 on f0.TrnDocumentID=f1.TrnDocumentID
```